# How can I add axis labels to a plot with custom axes?

Tags: r, label, histogram, axis, axis-labels

I want to add axes labels to the plot generated by the following code. Specifically, I would want an x-axis label that reads "Fibril Diameter (nm)" and a y-axis label that reads "Density". Any idea how I could accomplish this? Thanks!

```
den1 = density(CDE1$V1)
den2 = density(CDE1$V2)

col1 = hsv(h = 0.65, s = 0.6, v = 0.8, alpha = 0.5)
col2 = hsv(h = 0.85, s = 0.6, v = 0.8, alpha = 0.5)

op = par(mar = c(3, 3, 2, 2))
plot.new( )
plot.window(xlim = c(25,65), ylim = c(0, 0.14))
axis(side = 1, pos = 0, at = seq(from = 25, to = 65, by = 5), col = "gray20", 
     lwd.ticks = 0.25, cex.axis = 1, col.axis = "gray20", lwd = 1.5)
axis(side = 2, pos = 25, at = seq(from = 0, to = 0.14, by = 0.02), col = "gray20", 
     las = 2, lwd.ticks = 0.5, cex.axis = 1, col.axis = "gray20", lwd = 1.5)
polygon(den1$x, den1$y, col = col1, border ="black",lwd = 2)
polygon(den2$x, den2$y, col = col2, border ="black",lwd = 2)
text(52, 0.10, labels ="CDET", col =col1, cex = 1.25,font=2)
text(35, 0.03, labels ="SDFT", col =col2, cex = 1.25,font=2)
par(op)
title(main="Gestational Day 100/283")
```

Here's a picture of what the code generates so far...
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZCMk.jpg)

Comment: I suggest use ggplot2, much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your axis labels using `title()`

```r
title(main="Gestational Day 100/283", 
      xlab="Fibril Diameter (nm)",
      ylab="Density")
```

or with `mtext()` which will make it easier for you to fine-tune their exact positioning:

```r
mtext("Fibril Diameter (nm)", side=1, line=2)
mtext("Density", side=2, line=2)
```

In either case, you will probably need to increase your bottom and left plot margins so that the labels are actually visible, e.g. like this:

```r
op = par(mar=c(4.5, 4.5, 2, 2))
```